# Are the John Schultz commentaries good?

Tags: bible

Please let me know if these commentaries are reputable.

http://www.bible-commentaries.com/

I'm looking for legitimate pdf's that are open source equivalents for the Word Bible commentaries.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  The reason there are four votes to close this question is because the answers you seek will almost certainly be opinion based.  Please take the Christianity Tour (see link in the blue box at the bottom) and this link which explains what sort of questions are allowed: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The following article may provide useful inormation regarding the Christian and Missionary Alliance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_and_Missionary_Alliance

Comment: Sometimes question perfection at stack exchange is limiting.  I really have no other place to ask.  What if these commentaries are incorrect?

Comment: Whether they're correct or not probably depends on who you ask. If you don't know where I'm coming from, you won't know whether you consider my opinion relevant. What kind of person/approach would you trust to give you the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Are John Schultz' commentaries useful?

You ask if these commentaries are reputable or good. You express concern that they may be incorrect.

My answer is basically a **frame challenge**. No commentary is trustworthy, when compared with the biblical texts they comment on. You will need to read sections on scripture you know well, and compare it to other commentaries, if you want to see if it is useful for you. Schultz has biases, as we all do. Some of his ideas are doubtless erroneous. Your trust needs to be in the Bible and in your personal relationship with God. If Schultz' work compares favorably with other commentaries you have tried, then begin to use it to give you new ideas, but know that as you mature you will come to see errors in it.

Schultz' work is not exactly what we would call 'open source'. He makes it freely available for personal use in the form of pdf files which you prefer. But the work is copyrighted and may not be freely republished nor extensively quoted.

Schultz comes from a Protestant background, and I am comfortable that the Christian and Missionary Alliance is generally sound -- but this is only my **personal opinion** and you should be reluctant to trust it for your spiritual health.

My recommendation is to explore Schultz' commentary and use it to the extent it proves helpful and trustworthy to you. Please do compare it with other commentaries. [The Word Bible software](http://www.theword.net) contains several commentaries free of copyright, which you can use without restriction. **In my opinion** the Gill and Matthew Henry (probably short version) would be useful for comparison. Many other commentaries are available at the sites https://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/ and https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ . I want to suggest one very recent commentary which is also available as pdf files: https://planobiblechapel.org/constable-notes/ .

I hope you will grow spiritually by exposing yourself to all of these, and that you will continue to trust the Bible as much more reliable than any commentary on it.